# is there a quick way to remove all "create" strings from a SQL DB?

Tags: sql, editing

I am in the process of moving a database from one hosting service to another. The new hosting service cannot support databases with `create` language for tables, etc if they already exist.

It will probably take about 5-10 min to edit the SQL file but I was wondering if there is a quick way to do this?

Comment: What exactly is a "create language for tables"?

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+F

--->

create

--->

DEL

I hope you don't have arthritis. =)

That or you could run a pregmatch in a scripting language like PHP or Python.